# Drupal URL encoding breaks redirects/links

Tags: 7, uri, navigation

I added a link to my Toolbar Shortcuts list and the path is:

`admin/content?title=&type=slides&author=&status=All&vid=All`

But when you click it, Drupal redirects to:

```
admin/content%3Ftitle%3D%26type%3Dslides%26author%3D%26status%3DAll%26vid%3DAll
```

Which breaks the link and redirects to a wrong page.

How do I prevent Drupal from converting symbols and leave it as it is.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that you simply stated facts, without asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporal workaround, create views with friendly URLs for pages you need, e.g. now each exposed filtered result has its own views page.

Can't come up with anything else since Drupal 'works this way'.

Answer (score 0):

This is drupal core functionality that converts special correctors to string when using in toolbar shortcut menu.